# String-to-array conversion, array_rand, unset, and back to array-to-string. Is there a shortcut?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I am programming a schedule a phone call page. One of the `functions` I'm writing gets the `available assistants(saved as assistant_ids)` at the selected time picks a random one, removes him from the list, and updates the table. Pretty much straight forward.
I have written the code for it and it works perfectly well however, this code uses a lot of functions to do the process. And I feel like I'm scratching my left ear with my right foot! 
Is there a shortcut to all of this code which in the future would save a lot of processing for the server?

```
$assistants = self::get_avail_assists($table, $this->time);
        //Assistants are saved as ids and each one is 18 Char.
        //each one separated with a space
        $assistants_no = strlen($assistants);
            if($assistants_no > 1){
                for($i=0; $i<$assistants_no; $i=$i+18){
                    $assistants_array[$i/18] = substr($assistants,$i,17);
                }
            }

        //select random assistant key
        $rand_assistant_key = array_rand($assistants_array);
        //retrieve selected assistant
        $rand_assistant = $assistants_array[$rand_assistant_key];
        //delete selected assistant from list
        unset($assistants_array[$rand_assistant_key]);

        //clear assistants string
        $assistants = "";
        //recreate assistants string to update
        foreach($assistants_array as $assistant){
            $assistants .= $assistant." ";
        }
        //update database after popping out the random assistant
        $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".
        "avail_assists='".$assistants."' ".
        "WHERE id='".$this->time."' ".
        "LIMIT 1";
        mysqli_query($sql,etc...
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If the ids don't contain a space then you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php instead of looping. Also idk why you are saving `$rand_assistant` if you aren't going to use it.

Comment: Saving as in storing in a variable

Comment: @bassxzero Thank you for the comments. Now the `explode` function saves some looping for sure. And I'm using `rand_assistant` first of all to be fair to the assistants and the variable is going to be `returned` to the calling function

Comment: is there a reason your storing the data the way you are? as I would think if you used the table to store each of the id's in a row instead of having all the id's packed into one row. could make things easier. then you'd just have to query for a random row which can be done via sql, and then set the result as your random assistant and fire off another query to remove that id from the table. but that would require storing the data in the table much differently so I don't know if that's something that can be done.

Comment: @KitRamos the `table` contains an `id` _timestamp of the selected time period_ and `avail_assists` _ids of the assistants at that timestamp_. So to do as you've suggested would require to alter the `table` to `id`, `timestamp`, and `assistant`. So basically more **rows** for less **processing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it doesn't matter what order the assistants are re-entered into the database...

```
$ass_array=explode(" ",$assistants);  // space-separated string to array

shuffle($ass_array);    // mix it up
$lucky_ass=$ass_array[0];   // save one for whatever usage
unset($ass_array[0]);  // remove the one from the group

$leftover_string_of_asses=implode(' ',$ass_array);  // convert array to space-separated string

...add sql query
```

Comment: This really looks like the ultimate shortcut to the code. thank you very much for your time. PS: _I love how you called them **ass** though_ :D

Comment: You are welcome.  A pleasure to help.  (...yeah, I couldn't help myself on the variable naming)